Errors in result when performing logistic regression with one dependent and one independent binary variable
I have a dataset, df, with one dependent variable with levels "0" and "1" and one independent variable with levels "1" and "2". On performing logistic regression, the code below only returns a confusion matrix with outputs classified under category "1" and no "0"s. I have tried increasing the probability cutoff to 0.65 and 0.7. The results don't change. This is an example data frame; the original dataset has nearly 4500 rows of data.
data frame:
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1),
                 V2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1))
df
#>    V1 V2
#> 1   0  1
#> 2   1  1
#> 3   1  1
#> 4   0  1
#> 5   0  1
#> 6   1  1
#> 7   1  2
#> 8   0  1
#> 9   1  2
#> 10  1  1
#> 11  1  1
#> 12  0  1
#> 13  0  1
#> 14  1  1

# set levels
df$V1 <- factor(df$V1,
                    levels = c(0, 1),
                    labels = c("False", "True")
)

# Splitting dataset
split <- caTools::sample.split(df, SplitRatio = 0.8)
split
df$V1<-factor(df$V1)
train_reg <- subset(df, split == "TRUE")
test_reg <- subset(df, split == "FALSE")

# Training model
logistic_model <- glm(V1 ~ V2, 
                      data = train_reg, 
                      family = "binomial")
logistic_model

# Summary
summary(logistic_model)

predict_reg <- predict(logistic_model, 
                       test_reg, type = "response")
predict_reg

# Changing probabilities
predict_reg <- ifelse(predict_reg >0.5, 2, 1)


# Evaluating model accuracy
# using confusion matrix
table(test_reg$V1, predict_reg)


I don't see the results you describe with your sample data.

you should pass a vector to caTools::sample.split() rather than df

I think you're using caTools::sample.split wrong.

sample.split( Y, SplitRatio = 2/3, group = NULL )
Arguments:
Y: Vector of data labels. If there are only a few labels (as is expected) than relative ratio of data in both subsets will be the same.

If you look at the result of your sample.split call:
> split <- caTools::sample.split(df, SplitRatio = 0.8)
> split
[1] FALSE  TRUE

I think it's interpreting the two columns of your data set as a vector of two observations.  The result is that you happen to split your data by odd- and even-numbered cases (because R automatically replicates the (FALSE, TRUE) vector to match the number of rows of your data set).  For the particular example you have given us, we end up with complete separation for the training set (with(train_reg, table(V1, V2)) shows that zero values in the response V1 only occur for V2==1), as well as a testing set that has only one value of V2 (all are equal to 1), so the predictions for the testing set will all be equal (in this case all predicted probabilities are 0.4), so any threshold you pick will give you either all zeros or all ones for the predicted value ...
In any case, what you want is something like:
split <- caTools::sample.split(df$V1, SplitRatio = 0.8)
split
##  [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
## [13]  TRUE  TRUE

That said, it's not obvious why this should be happening for your real data set unless it happens that the even rows of your data set have only one of the possible values of V2 (unlikely unless either the data set is extremely unbalanced or there is some unusual structure in your data set related to odd/even rows)
If I redo your model fit and summaries with sample.split used in the correct way I get both predicted values (I still have complete separation in the test set, so the predicted probabilities are either 0.5 or 1):
print(predict_reg0 <- predict(logistic_model,
  test_reg, type = "response"))
##   6   7   8 
## 0.5 1.0 0.5 
print(predict_reg <- ifelse(predict_reg0 >0.5, 2, 1))
## 6 7 8 
## 1 2 1 
table(test_reg$V1, predict_reg)
##        predict_reg
##        1 2
##  False 1 0
##  True  1 1


I am not convinced. The sample dataset should include both dependent and independent variable. What passing a vector would do? In the original dataset we have 160 observations of type "2" in variable V2 and 1980 observations of type "1" in variable V2. I don't think this is an extremely unbalanced dataset.

Passing the vector is clearly what the documentation is asking for. I can't say any more about what's going wrong without a reproducible example; I've explained what goes wrong, and just edited my answer that we do indeed get sensible answers in the example you provided.
